# Smart pointer blows stack due to recursive delete

Tags: c++, memory-management, recursion, stack-overflow, smart-pointers

Simple data structures, for instance linked lists, where the 'next' pointer is a smart pointer.  When the head node gets deleted, the smart pointer for 'next' kicks in and does a recursive delete.  For a long list, this quickly blows the stack.

I have had to go back to replace these smart pointers with simple, raw pointers.  Am I missing something here?

Comment: 'blows the stack'? can you elaborate please.

Comment: Almost surely this is not the smart pointer's fault. Show us some code, there's bound to be a bug in the implementation. In any event, complete list deletion should be by iteration, not recursion, so it should take constant stack space.

Comment: @Kerrek: presumably, the smart pointer's destructor deletes the pointee, which will give recursion if the pointee contains another smart pointer. I don't see how the smart pointer could be implemented to avoid that.

Comment: AH I think I see what you mean - the recursion is too deep for the size of a fixed size stack!

Comment: @Mike: I see how this could happen, but that just means that the list data structure isn't well designed. We could tell from seeing the actual code, though.

Comment: It's a simple linked list of fixed size blocks.  CompSci 101.  I happened to load a VERY LARGE jpeg into it by mistake and my standard block size was too small, resulting in a very long list.  However, it seems to have exposed a potential issue with using smart pointers in recursive data structures.

Comment: @Kerrek: Sorry, I misread your first comment - I thought it said "this *is* the smart pointer's fault", and replied disagreeing with that (and agreeing with what you actually wrote).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming I've understood you right and both `head` and `next` are smart pointers you can avoid this by doing:

```
head = head->next;
```

Or equivalent. Your 'old' head will get deleted and the old second place item will get promoted to the head. All in one consistent change, with no deep recursion. The only pre-condition to this is that head is not `NULL` to begin with.

As Mike pointed out in the comment if the goal is to delete the whole list then you can repeat that within a loop.

Comment: Yes, so you can delete the whole list non-recursively with `while (head) head = head->next;`

Comment: Don't forget to comment it, because someone will come and go WTF :)

Comment: "Your 'old' head will get deleted and the old second place item will get promoted to the head. " - That statement, while reflective of what is happening, is an incredible simplification. Unless the casual reader is *very* well versed in both the language mechanics and smart-pointer functionality, this solution, while it works, is more magic than anything else. And if they are so-said familiar, they likely don't need it in the first place. A step-by-step of exactly what is happening during that simple `head=head->next` assignment would make this *substantially* clearer.

Answer (score 2):

Smart pointers on the internals of a linked list class doesn't seem to buy you very much. Raw pointers seems perfectly reasonable to me. I think smart pointers are best used for less controlled situations where it would be easy to forget to delete something.

Mind you must have been a huge list to blow the stack, are you sure you didn't have a bug in your code?

Comment: Smart pointers in the internals buy you might higher exception safety guarantees. For free in terms of labour and very little extra constant storage cost. That alone seems to be worth it to me.

Comment: Well, I use a smart pointer to hold a newly created node before it gets attached to the list.  But, once attached, it is the list node's destructor's responsibility.  As you guys noted, I have to do manual processing in the destructor anyway to replace the automatic smart-pointer recursion with hand-coded iteration.  Could you please elaborate on the exception safety issues.  I thought that any unhandled exception in a destructor will kill the program anyway -- regardless of smart pointers.

Comment: It's more useful during creation/editing of the list than destruction, for ensuring that things do still get destroyed even when something goes awry.

Comment: I suspect that your `std::list` is implemented without smart pointers and is perfectly exception safe. E.g using try-catch-deallocate-rethrou to deal with failure of copying user's object; and that's a single function where something might go wrong. With smart pointer, you'd have to use a custom deallocator (that uses allocator) and release the smart pointer if everything goes right - not one bit less work.